Python directory ModuleNotFoundError
I have simple fastapi project. I have 3 directory and i am calling my model from other directory its showing that
from shakeitupapp.models.category import CategoryModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shakeitupapp'
You can see my file structure i have added init in each directory

And the file i am calling is simply this
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder


class CategoryModel(BaseModel):
    categoryName: str = Field(...)
    categoryType: Optional[str] = None


I tru to import like these 2 but nothing works
from shakeitupapp.models.category import CategoryModel
from ..models.category import CategoryModel


You should start your app from project root (because your imports start from project root). Hence go 1 directory up and run python shakeitupapp/datafetching/category_fetch.py

@sudden_appearance tried also but not working.

@Umaizkhan does your PYTHONPATH environment variable have a reference to the root of your project in the terminal (Either by a . when running from root or explicitly specifying the path?).

you may see similar problems in many questions on Stackoverflow - so probably you could resolve it few hours ago without asking question.  It can run your code from different folder - and then it has different Current Working Directory (which you can see with print( os.getcwd() ) - and it search your modules in different folder. One solution is to change folder with cd folder in system before running script, or with os.chdir(...) in code before imports. Other method is add your folder with project to sys.path before import, or add it to system varialble PYTHONPATH.

image shows that you run code in folder shakeitupapp so it search subfolder shakeitupapp in this folder - so it search D:/shakeitup/shakeitupapp/shakeitupapp/__init__.py. - with two shakeitupapp in path. If you go to parent folder cd .. then it will search D:/shakeitup/shakeitupapp/__init__.py with single shakeitupapp in path. - because it search relative to current position where you run python.exe, not relative to code category_fetch.py

other idea (but didn't check it): don't run directly category_fetch.py but create D:/shakeitup/main.py which will add os.path.abspath(__file__) to sys.path and it will import shakeitupapp.datafetching.category_fetch.py to run it - and later run only main.py

Python searches your module using folder in which you run python.exe, not folder where is category_fetch.py
You run code Python.exe in folder D:/shakeitup/shakeitupapp/ so category_fetch.py searches it in
"D:/shakeitup/shakeitupapp/" + "shakeitupapp/_init_.py"

but it is in
"D:/shakeitup/" + "shakeitupapp/_init_.py"

If  you move to parent folder cd D:/shakeitup/ (or cd ..) and run with longer path
python shakeitupapp/datafetching/category_fetch.py

then it should find module(s).
To make it simpler you can add D:/shakeitup to PYTHONPATH and then you can run python.exe in any folder.

Eventually in code you can use sys.path.append("D:/shakeitup") before import but this will need changes when you move all code to different folder. It can be better to calculate this path using something like this
CURRENT = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath(__file__) )
BASE = os.join(CURRENT, "..", "..")
BASE = os.path.abspath(BASE)

sys.path.append(BASE)


Other idea (but didn't check it): don't run directly category_fetch.py
but create D:/shakeitup/main.py which will add os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) to sys.path
and it will import shakeitupapp.datafetching.category_fetch to run it.
And later run only main.py.
If you have more scripts in folders then in main.py you could use argpaser to get parameters and select which script to import and run.
